# Office Dialog Api unable to be closed

Tags: outlook-web-addins

We are using the Office Dialog Api for our O365 Outlook addin.
On the web, the dialog opened from the api cannot be closed either from the native "x" in the top right corner or with the dialog.close() method. The innerHtml gets removed but the dialog window itself does not close.
This issue persists with the "displayInIframe" property set to true or false.

Updated:

This issue does not occur on the Outlook Desktop (windows or mac). Only occurs on web instances (used chrome).

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, options.dialogOptions,
    (asyncResult) => {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
            $log.debug('Display Dialog Error: ', asyncResult.error);
        }
        else {
            _dialog = asyncResult.value;
            if (options.params) {
        _dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, handleDialogMessageEvent);
        _dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, eventReceivedHandler);
```

Comment: Hi jchoi, can you please give some more information about this issue? The snippet of code you're using to invoke the API, and which browser you are attempting this on would all be helpful. Additionally, have you tried other browsers, and does this issue occur in Outlook Desktop?

Comment: I hit this issue as well. Using Firefox 60.0.2 on Linux.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with IE and Edge and Outlook Desktop

Answer (score 0):

This issue was found in Office 365 Outlook on the Web. A fix to resolve this issue has already rolled out to production. If the issue still persists, please try refreshing your browser's cache.

Comment: refreshing did not resolve this issue. Hard reloaded as well.